# Load balancer /target group relationship query

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, elastic-load-balancer

I cannot seem to find anywhere in the AWS load balancer console a field which tells me which target group is associated with the particular load balancer.I think I remember which one I configured, but I just want to confirm that the correct target group is associated with the correct load balancer and I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the 'Load Balancers' console you can go to the Listeners tab and look at the link in *forwarding to*.

Alternately you can click on 'Target Groups' in the left side menu and search for your load balancer in the Load Balancer column:

The `aws` cli method would look something like this:

```
$ aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers \
    --query 'LoadBalancers[*].[LoadBalancerArn]' \
    --output text | xargs -I {} aws elbv2 describe-target-groups \
    --load-balancer-arn {} \
    --query 'TargetGroups[].TargetGroupName'
```